# VBA to add mmm-yy and Business Quarter for a date

Tags: vba, excel

I have created a VBA to automatically populate date when the dropdown is selected, but need the date formatted as `mmm-yy` and Business quarter to be populated in the next cells.

Here is what I have created and please assist in adding mmm-yy and Business quarter.

```
With Target
    If .Column <> 10 Or .Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
    If .Value = "Select" Then
        If .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
            .Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
            .Offset(0, 1).Value = Now - 1      
        End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the business quarter is a bit subjective. Fiscal years change between regions. The example below assume Jan-Mar = Q1, Apr-Jun = Q2 etc:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    With Target
        If .Column <> 10 Or .Row < 1 Then Exit Sub
        If .Value = "Select" Then
            If .Offset(0, 1).Value = "" Then
                .Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                .Offset(0, 1).Value = Now - 1
                .Offset(0, 2).Value = Now - 1
                .Offset(0, 2).NumberFormat = "mmm-yy" '<~~ mmm-yy
                .Offset(0, 3).Value = GetBusinessQuarter(.Offset(0, 1)) '<~~ business quarter
            End If
        End If
    End With

End Sub

Function GetBusinessQuarter(dt As Date) As String

    ' credit: https://exceljet.net/formula/get-fiscal-quarter-from-date
    GetBusinessQuarter = "Q" & CStr(Choose(Month(dt), 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4))

End Function
```

Comment: Thats awesome, can you also assist with Week number for that month?

Comment: Side note: alternatively you may calculate *GetBusinessQuarter()* via Integer division: `GetBusinessQuarter = "Q" & (Month(dt) - 1) \ 3 + 1`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of all this, look at the DatePart function. It does weeks, quarters, DOW, etc.